# How to perform automatic, lossless cutting / splitting / chopping of video files?

Tags: windows, macos, video, splitter

I have various video files in H264 / xvid / mp4 / avi codecs/containers.

Some of them are very long and I'd like to chop them down into 10 minute long segments.

Are there any tools that can automatically and losslessly split such video files according to a given segment length?

A solution for either OS X or Windows will do.

Answer (score 1):

I like Avidemux. Can't say if this is something you want to use or not, but you can't beat the price - free!!! And there's a version for Mac, Windows and even Linux!

Avidemux is extremely fast as long as you're not transcoding (from like AVI to MP4 or something) too.

Check it out: http://www.avidemux.org

Answer (score 1):

"Avidemux" is a fine choice.

"VirtualDub" has a multi-segment mode and is very popular FOSS software.

"Avi Splitter" could work for you, even though it only works based on segment sizes, not length.

Even "Easy Video Splitter" could work, even though it's quite old software.

"MP4Box" will also do what you need and you could try a GUI to make your life easier, like "YAMB".

Answer (score 0):

Avidemux doesn't automatically split a video into segments - you have to do it manually.  For example, if you have a 2 hour video and want to split it into 10 minute segments, which would be 12 total, there is no auto function for that.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)